# How to align h2 within a nested div?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align the text within my h2 element. I would like it to be centered vertically within the div. I'm working in .NET MVC

My html: (this is the only part giving me trouble)
Specifically:

```css
.banner-side-container {
  height: 240px;
  width: 180px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.banner-side-container h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.view-teams-banner {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 110px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.view-matches-banner {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 110px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: darkorchid;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <div class="banner-side-container">
    <div class="view-teams-banner">
      <h2>View Teams</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="view-matches-banner">
      <h2>View Matches</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

I've tried adding vertical-align: middle; to all 4 selectors with no success.
Further info: the text-align: center; worked perfectly.

Comment: There’s nothing with C# here. Removed the tag

Comment: one method of centering is with flex box, add `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` to `.view-teams-banner`

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex and add the following settings to the three elements wrapping the `h2`s and their parent elements as follows:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

```css
.banner-side-container {
  height: 240px;
  width: 180px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.banner-side-container h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.view-teams-banner {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 110px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.view-matches-banner {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 110px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: darkorchid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <div class="banner-side-container">
    <div class="view-teams-banner">
      <h2>View Teams</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="view-matches-banner">
      <h2>View Matches</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```